# How to import metapost to .tex properly and how to do it without importing

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I have read several questions related to metapost and latex here on TEX SE, but I still cannot solve my own problem.

So it is a very basic problem. I am trying to include a metapost graphic in my .tex file. What I did is I save another .mp file that has this code

```
beginfig (1);  
  % draw a line  
  draw (1cm,2cm) -- (3cm,5cm);  
endfig;  
end.
```

Then in my .tex code, I use the package graphicx, then write \includegraphics{trial.mp}, where trial is the name of my .mp file.

But it did not work.

Next I tried to change the code to \includegraphics{trial.mps}, it printed the diagram but with a file name (trial) on top. And I don't want that, I just want the picture.

1. My question is what is the difference between .mp and .mps?

Not satisfied, I tried to write the code immediately on my .tex file by using the package mpgraphics

```
\begin{mpdisplay}  
draw (1cm,2cm) -- (5cm,3cm) ;  
\end{mpdisplay}
```

But it did not work.

2. My next question is, is there any way I can write the metapost code inside my .tex code so that I don't have to import from other file?

Many many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

I hope not coming too late… About your second question, I use two solutions regularly to integrate MetaPost code directly into a LaTeX document.

The first method is using the [`gmp` package](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/gmp/gmp.pdf) already mentioned by dgoodmaniii.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost*}
beginfig(1);
$ := 1;
for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
  % draw a line  
  draw (1cm,2cm) -- (3cm,5cm); 
endfor;
endfig;          
\end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```

You must run either LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX on it with the `shell-escape` option, if you want to produce your drawing directly, like with this example (`pdflatex`):

```
pdflatex --shell-escape mypic.tex
```

In this case, a MetaPost file `mypic+mp0001.mp` is created, then compiled to produce a `mypic+mp0001.mps` file which is eventually included in your LaTeX program. All this "on the fly".

Otherwise (without the `shellescape` option for the `gmp` package, or without the `--shell-escape` option of the `pdflatex` command), the first run will only produce the  MetaPost file  `mypic+mp0001.mp`. You will have to process it and then include the resulting `.mps` image, all this by yourself. Or you may execute a shell script to take care of these steps: `mypic+mp.sh`, which is also created during the first run.

You can see that the `shell-escape` way is by far preferable :-)

The other way I know of to integrate MetaPost code in a LaTeX program is to use LuaLaTeX and its [`luamplib` package](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
$ := 1;
for i = -.3cm step .6cm until 3.6cm:
  % draw a line  
  draw (1cm,2cm) -- (3cm,5cm); 
endfor;
endfig;          
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is the most direct and straightforward solution: no importing, no `shell-escape` option needed. But it is LuaLaTeX-specific, contrary to `gmp` which can be used on any engine (LaTeX+DVI, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX…).

Either way, your picture will be nicely drawn in your document:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Metapost is a declarative graphics language; the program describes the image but is not the image itself.  You have to *compile* the `mp` file to produce the `mps` file which `pdftex` includes.  Depending on your OS, something like this should do it:

```
mpost image.mp
```

This will produce a file `image.1`, which you rename `image.mps` to include it with `pdftex`.  (There are ways to make Metapost produce a file ending in `.mps`, and ways to make `pdftex` accept files with `.1`, but I leave these as an exercise in reading the documentation.)

For including Metapost source within your TeX source, look into the `gmp` package.

Hope that helps.