# Generate analog clock with numbered face, add seconds, Roman numerals

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, datetime, roman-numerals

Looking at the excellent answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face/), I can't help wondering how I can accomplish two apparently simple modifications:

1. I wanted to be able to generate a traditional Roman-number clock;
2. It would be very helpful to add seconds to the labels, so that it would be easy to help children learn how to tell time with an analog clock.

MWE from Harish Kumar's answer to the previous question:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\clock[4][2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,line cap=round,line width=#1*3pt]
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!20] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
{
\draw[line width=#1*1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node[scale=#1]{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=#1*2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red,scale=#1] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*2pt] (0,0) -- (-#2*30-#3*30/60:0.7cm); % hours
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-#3*6:1cm); % minutes
\draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*.6pt,red] (0,0) -- (-#4*6:1.2cm); % seconds
\path [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%\syntax
%% \clock[<optional scaling dim>]{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
\noindent\clock{9}{35}{55}\clock[1.2]{1}{15}{30} \clock[.9]{2}{25}{15}
\clock[.7]{12}{58}{10} \clock[.5]{6}{10}{55}
\clock[.3]{12}{20}{22} \clock[.2]{8}{0}{5}


\end{document}
```

I'm guessing it's something similar to:

```
\foreach \angle / \label in
{0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10, 180/9,
210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4}
{
\draw[line width=#1*1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node[scale=#1]{\textsf{\label}};
}
```

But I cannot figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Both Heiko's and Harish's answers are beautiful; I cannot decide between them... I guess that's because I asked two questions in one.

Comment: [I'm a bit late to the party but...](http://cl.ly/image/3l2B1f30062o?_ga=1.90816089.251946421.1445524467)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I like to use styles and the key system of PGF as much as I can, so I made this little solution.

I added the PGFmath functions `croman` and `cRoman` that take an integer number and output a string (i.e. it can't be used as a mathematical input to another function) in Roman numerals. The `c` denotes the fact that ["IIII"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Alternative_forms) is used instead of "IV".

As PGFmath functions cannot be redeclared with the `declare function` key I'm using `.code` keys with a helper macro `\clockF`. Not the best solution but it'll work here.

The last example redefines these functions for the second (minutes) and the third (seconds) level.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{cRoman}{1}{%
  \pgfmathcroman@{#1}\edef\pgfmathresult{\uppercase{\pgfmathresult}}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{croman}{1}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathint@{#1}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult<0\relax\let\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
    \else\ifnum\pgfmathresult=4\def\pgfmathresult{iiii}%
    \else\edef\pgfmathresult{\romannumeral\pgfmathresult}\fi\fi
  \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\clockset[1]{\pgfqkeys{/clock}{#1}}
\pgfset{/pgf/declare function={angle(\i,\t)=90-360/\t*\i;
                               hide(\i,\n)=ifthenelse(mod(\i,\n)==0,"","\i");}}
\newcommand*\clockF[2]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/f-#1/.@cmd}#2\pgfeov}
\clockset{
  clock/.style={
    name=c, ultra thick, circle, draw, minimum size=+6cm, outer sep=-.5\pgflinewidth},
  f-1/.code={angle(#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/l-1})},
  f-2/.code={angle(#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/l-2})},
  f-3/.code={angle(#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/l-3})},
  v-1/.initial=0, v-2/.initial=0, v-3/.initial=0, % 0:00:00
  every hand/.style={draw, line cap=round},
  levels/.initial=3, l-1/.initial=12, l-2/.initial=60, l-3/.initial=60,
  line path/.style n args={3}{
    insert path={(c.{\clockF{#2}{#1}}) -- ++({180+\clockF{#2}{#1}}:#3)}},
  hand path/.style n args={3}{insert path={(c.center) -- ++ ({\clockF{#2}{#1}}:#3)}},
  l-1-path/.style={draw, /clock/line path={#1}{1}{.4cm}},
  l-2-path/.style={draw, /clock/line path={#1}{2}{.1cm}},
  l-1-node/.style={font=\large, pos=1, anchor={\clockF{1}{#1}},
                   node contents={\pgfmathprint{cRoman(#1)}}},
  l-2-node/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny,  pos=0, inner sep=+3pt, anchor=south,
                   rotate={-90+\clockF{2}{#1}}, node contents={#1}},
  l-3-node/.style={shape=coordinate},
  hand-1-path/.style={/clock/every hand, /clock/hand path={#1}{1}{1.0cm}, ultra thick},
  hand-2-path/.style={/clock/every hand, /clock/hand path={#1}{2}{1.4cm}, thick},
  hand-3-path/.style={/clock/every hand, /clock/hand path={#1}{3}{1.8cm}},
  time/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    /clock/v-1={#1+(#2+(#3)/60)/60}, /clock/v-2={#2+(#3)/60}, /clock/v-3={#3}}}
\newcommand*\clock[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}\clockset{#1}
\node[/clock/clock] {};
\foreach \level in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/levels},...,1}{
  \foreach \ll in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/l-\level}}
    \path[/clock/l-\level-path/.try=\ll] node[/clock/l-\level-node/.try=\ll] {};
  \path[/clock/hand-\level-path/.try=\pgfkeysvalueof{/clock/v-\level}];}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\clock[time=10:10:25]
\clock[l-2-node/.append style={pos=1, node contents=\pgfmathprint{hide(#1,5)},
anchor={ifthenelse(and(#1<45,#1>15),270,90)},rotate={ifthenelse(and(#1<45,#1>15),180,0)}}]
\clock[time=19:05:20, l-1=24, clock/.append style={rectangle},
  l-1-node/.append style={font=\small, node contents={#1}},
  f-2/.code={angle(#1,120)}, f-3/.code={180-angle(#1,120)}, l-2-path/.append style={red},
  l-2-node/.style={pos=1, red, font=\sffamily\tiny, sloped, anchor=east, scale=.75,
                   inner sep=+1pt, node contents={\pgfmathprint{hide(#1,5)}}},
  hand-2-path/.append style=red, hand-3-path/.append style=blue,
  l-3-path/.style={draw=blue, /clock/line path={#1}{3}{.1cm}},
  /tikz/execute at end picture={\sffamily\tikzset{nodes={inner sep=+2pt}}
    \draw[red, -latex] (90:+1.45cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-180, radius=+1.45cm]
      node[midway, sloped, above]{\tiny Minutes};
    \draw[blue, -latex] (90:+1.85cm) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=+180, radius=+1.85cm]
      node[midway, sloped, above, rotate=180]{\tiny Seconds};}]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice use of proper clock Roman numerals, especially the use of IIII for four.

Comment: Welcome back :-)

Comment: +1 for the 24-hour clock. I have a (real) fully mechanical Russian clock ("Raketa", I think) that my father bought from a sailor more than 40 years ago and then gave to me... a really cherished memory (but well, minutes and seconds are traditional as in the 12-hour clock, only the hour hand was 24-hours).

Comment: @Rmano Thank you. The arrangement of the minutes and seconds is just something different. I don't think there's a watch that displays that. I just wanted to show how easy it can be to change such trivial aspects without re-writing the whole document with the use of styles and no hard-coded values. Using a shape for the whole clock (here a `rectangle`) and the use of the angular borders make it even easier (and `style`-able). (And with `execute at end picture` you can basically cheat everything in there.)

Answer (score 41):

There is a much simpler sans-seconds solution given in [Reproducing an analog clock similar to the one provided by the ifsym package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49427/reproducing-an-analog-clock-similar-to-the-one-provided-by-the-ifsym-package)

But without bling what does a TikZ answer do good for anyways?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\def\hourhand{1}
\def\minutehand{47}
\def\secondhand{32}
\begin{tikzpicture}[r/.style={font=\sffamily,inner sep=0,rotate=-30*\x,anchor=north},
s/.style={even odd rule,top color=black,bottom color=black,middle color=white}]

\shade[s,shading angle=-10] circle (21mm) circle (22mm);
\shade[s,shading angle=15]  circle (22mm) circle (25mm);

\foreach\x[evaluate={\xf=int(5*\x);}] in{1,...,12}{
\draw ({30*(3-\x)}:19mm) node[r,anchor=south,scale=0.5,inner sep=1pt] {\xf}
node[r,scale=1.5,xscale=0.85] at ({30*(3-\x)}:1.8cm) 
                               {\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\x}};
\ifodd\x\else\draw (30*\x:18mm-2.5ex)--++(30*\x:-1mm);\fi
}

\foreach\x in{1,...,60}{\draw (6*\x:18mm)--++(6*\x:1mm);}
\draw circle(18mm) circle(19mm) circle(18mm-2.5ex) circle(17mm-2.5ex);

\begin{scope}[rotate around={-6*(\minutehand):(0,0)}]%\hourhand+
\fill(0.5mm,0) to[out=90,in=-100] (80:1.2cm) to[in=-80,out=120] (90:1.75cm)
to[out=-100,in=60] (100:1.2cm) to[in=90,out=-80](-0.5mm,0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[rotate around={-30*(\hourhand+\minutehand/60):(0,0)}]
\fill(0.5mm,0) to[out=90,in=-150] (70:6mm) to[in=-80,out=120] (90:1.4cm)
to[out=-100,in=60] (110:6mm) to[in=90,out=-30](-0.5mm,0);
\end{scope}
\draw[thick,-{Kite[scale=0.8]}] (0,0) -- (90-6*\secondhand:1.8cm); %Seconds
\filldraw[fill=white]circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see I suddenly got bored with the clock hands :)

Comment: Wow!!! That definitely adds some "bling". I'd keep it to myself instead of using this to teach children... However, I'm still at a loss trying to add some functionality -- like easily defining hours, minutes and seconds like `\clock{1}{15}{30}` above.

Comment: @Joseph Play around with `\hourhand,\minutehand` etc. values at the top. Or put everything inside a macro like the other answers :)

Comment: That is sexy.__

Answer (score 35):

Not claiming to add much in terms of functionality, but just more of an "icon" style clock:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{shaded/.style args={#1:#2:#3 @ #4}{
  left color=#1, right color=#3, middle color=#2, shading angle=#4
}}
\tikzset{pics/.cd, clock/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{code={
\tikzset{x=1ex, y=1ex, every path/.style={line cap=round}} 
\shade [shaded=black!75:black!50:black!25 @ 225] circle [radius=13];
\shade [shaded=black!75:black!50:black!25 @ 45]  circle [radius=12.5];
\fill [black!90] circle [radius=12];
\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=90-\i*30; \k=mod(\i,3)==0;\m=int(\i*5);}] in {1,...,12}
  \draw [white, line width=\k ? .4ex : .2ex] (\j:11.5) -- (\j:11-\k) 
    (\j:10) node [anchor=\j, text=black!20, font=\sffamily]  {\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\i}};
\shade [inner color=white, outer color=black, opacity=0.25] circle [radius=12];
\fill [gray!50, rotate=90-#1*30-#2/2-#3/120, 
  rounded corners=.5ex, drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5}]
  (-3/2,3/4) -- (-3/2,-3/4) -- (7,0) -- cycle;
\fill  [gray!50, rotate=90-#2*6-#3/60, 
  rounded corners=0.5ex, drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5}]
  (-3/2,3/4) -- (-3/2,-3/4) -- (11,0) -- cycle;
\fill [red!75!black, drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5}, rotate=90-#3*6] (0,-.1ex) rectangle (11,.1ex);
\shade [shaded=black!50:black!25:black!10 @ 225] circle [radius=1];
\shade [shaded=black!50:black!25:black!10 @ 45] circle [radius=3/4];
\fill [white, opacity=1/16] (0:11) arc (0:180:11) 
.. controls ++(-45:10) and ++(135:10) .. cycle;
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {clock={9:35:15}};
\pic at (0,5) {clock={3:15:55}};
\pic at (5,5) {clock={12:05:30}};
\pic at (5,0) {clock={6:20:43}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 34):

The hour values are written inside a loop:

```
\foreach \angle / \label in {
  0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10,
  180/9, 210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4
}{
  % ...
  \draw (\angle:1.4cm) node[scale=#1]{%
    \textsf{\label}%
  };
}
```

Macro `\label` contains the hour number, it can be converted via `\romannumeral`
to lowercase roman numbers and with `\uppercase` to uppercase roman numbers:

```
    \textsf{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\label}}%
```

The seconds are already provided in Harish Kumar's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236928/16967).
This version adds the seconds outside as small red numbers, for learning purposes.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\clock[4][2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,line cap=round,line width=#1*3pt]
    \filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!20] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \foreach \angle / \label in {
      0/3, 30/2, 60/1, 90/12, 120/11, 150/10,
      180/9, 210/8, 240/7, 270/6, 300/5, 330/4
    }{
      \draw[line width=#1*1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
      \draw (\angle:1.4cm) node[scale=#1]{%
        \textsf{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\label}}%
      };
    }   
    \foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
      \draw[line width=#1*2pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
    \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 11} {
      \node[text=red, font=\tiny, scale=#1] at (\i*30:2.2cm) {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{int(mod(75 - \i*5, 60))}%
        \textsf{\seconds}%
      };
    }   
    \node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red,scale=#1] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
    \draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*2pt] (0,0) -- (-#2*30-#3*30/60:0.7cm); % hour
    \draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-#3*6:1cm); % minutes
    \draw[rotate=90,line width=#1*.6pt,red] (0,0) -- (-#4*6:1.2cm); % seconds
    \path [fill=black] (0,0) circle (3pt);
    \path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    %
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%\syntax
%% \clock[<optional scaling dim>]{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
\noindent\clock{9}{35}{55}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ah! You nailed roman issue. +1

Comment: Is there analogous to `\romannumeral` for Alpha numeral?

Comment: @Sigur Not, there is no primitive. The LaTeX kernel defines `\@alph` and `\@Alph` at macro level to be used in `\alph` and `\Alph` for the formatting of counters. See also package [`alphalph`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph).

Answer (score 20):

Add these:

```
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {84,78,...,-270}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.9cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.7cm) node[scale=0.25]{\textsf{\label}};
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\clock[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line width=3pt]
\filldraw [fill=Goldenrod!30] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {60,30,...,-270}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.8cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.4cm) node{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle [count=\label] in {84,78,...,-270}
{
\draw[line width=1pt] (\angle:1.9cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\draw (\angle:1.7cm) node[scale=0.25]{\textsf{\label}};
}
\foreach \angle in {0,90,180,270}
\draw[line width=2.3pt] (\angle:1.6cm) -- (\angle:2cm);
\node[draw=none,font=\tiny,text=red] at (0,.9cm) {TICK-TOCK};
\draw[rotate=90,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (-#1*30-#2*30/60:0.7cm); % hours
\draw[rotate=90,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (-#2*6:1cm); % minutes
\draw[rotate=90,thin,red] (0,0) -- (-#3*6:1.2cm); % seconds
\path [fill=red] (0,0) circle (2pt);
%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%\syntax
%% \clock{<hour>}{<minute>}{<seconds>}
\noindent\clock{1}{15}{30}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use Heiko's techniques for roman numbers.

Answer (score 17):

A try with MetaPost, without much frills, but the result indicates the hour (in roman numerics), minute and second as required :-).

Hour, minute and second are given by the user as the three parameters of the `clock` macro, which draws the analog clock and a rudimentary numeric clock below it. This macro makes use of the `freelabel` instruction from the Metafun format, which allows correct placement of labels around a circle, and the `numprint` package for the numeric clock.

**EDIT** Now the last example gives the current hour, minute, *and* second. Current hour and minute are given by MetaPost internal variables `hour` and `minute` (see also Thruston's answer in this topic), but MetaPost has no variable for the current second. However, as Dohyun Kim (maintainer of the `luamplib` package) told me [in this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face/237263?noredirect=1#comment563312_237263) on [my attempt in the preceeding related subject](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/generate-analog-clock-with-numbered-face/237263#237263), Lua can produce it. So I've included Dohyun Kim's code in the last example:

```
second := \directlua{tex.sprint(os.date("*t").sec)};
```

The complete program:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, multi=mplibcode]{standalone}
\usepackage{numprint}
  \nplpadding{2}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \everymplib{
    verbatimtex \leavevmode etex;
    r := 4cm; len := 10bp; min_thickness := 1.75bp; hour_thickness := 3bp;

    def clock(expr hour, minute, second) =
      path cadran; cadran = fullcircle scaled (2r); 
      fill cadran scaled 1.025; fill cadran withcolor .9white; 

      for i = 1 upto 60:
        if i mod 5 = 0: 
          j := i div 5;
          angl := 90-30j; 
          freelabel("\large\sffamily\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral" & decimal j & "}", 
            (r-len)*dir angl, r*dir angl);
          draw ((r, 0) -- (r - len, 0)) rotated angl withpen pencircle scaled min_thickness;
        else:
          angl := 90 - 6i;
          draw ((r, 0) -- (r - .5len, 0)) rotated angl;
          freelabel("\tiny\sffamily" & decimal i, (r-.5len)*dir angl, r*dir angl);
        fi
      endfor;

      drawarrow (origin -- r*dir(90-second*6)) cutends (0, 1.5len) withcolor red;
      pickup pencircle scaled min_thickness;
      drawarrow origin -- r*dir(90-(minute+second/60)*6) cutends (0, 3.5len);
      pickup pencircle scaled hour_thickness;
      drawarrow origin -- r*dir (90-(hour+minute/60+second/3600)*30) cutends(0, 6len);

      fill fullcircle scaled len;
      pickup pencircle;
      labeloffset := .6cm;
      picture num_watch; 
      num_watch = thelabel.bot("\huge\ttfamily" & decimal hour 
        & ":\numprint{" & decimal minute & "}:\numprint{" & decimal second & "}", r*down); 
      fill bbox num_watch withcolor .9white; 
      draw bbox num_watch withpen pencircle; 
      draw num_watch;
    enddef;

    beginfig(1);
  }
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode} clock(0, 0, 0); \end{mplibcode}
  \begin{mplibcode} clock(2, 7, 3); \end{mplibcode}
  \begin{mplibcode} clock(3, 27, 43); \end{mplibcode}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    second := \directlua{tex.sprint(os.date("*t").sec)}; % Courtesy of Dohyun Kim 
    clock(hour, minute, second); 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

To be typeset with LuaLaTeX. Here are the outputs of the four different examples.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The last is thus the current time at the moment of the compilation:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Here's one I made earlier in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it). (This was originally written in raw PostScript years ago when my children were learning to tell the time).  I've updated it with optional roman numbers.

Use it like this to get a stamp of the current time:

```
beginfig(1)
draw clock(hour,minute)
endfig;
```

[image]

or like this to get a page of random clocks for your learner to practise.

```
beginfig(2);
  roman_numerals_please := 1;
  for i=0 upto 2:
    for j=0 upto 3:
       draw clock(floor(uniformdeviate 12), 5 * floor(uniformdeviate 12)) 
            shifted (1.414i*clock_diameter, 1.414j*clock_diameter);
    endfor 
  endfor
endfig;
```

[image]

Complete program:

```
prologues:=3;outputtemplate:="%j%c.eps";

vardef roman primary h = 
   if     h<5: ""  for i=1 upto h: & "I" endfor
   elseif h<9: "V" for i=6 upto h: & "I" endfor
   elseif h=9: "IX"
   else:       "X" for i=11 upto h: & "I" endfor
   fi
enddef;

newinternal clock_diameter; clock_diameter := 4cm; 
path hand[]; 
hand1 = origin .. (.257,1/50) .. (.377,1/60) & (.377,1/60) {up} .. (.40,3/50) .. (.60, 1/40) .. {right} (.75,0);
hand1 := (hand1 .. reverse hand1 reflectedabout(left,right) .. cycle) scaled 1/2 clock_diameter;

hand2 = origin  --- (.60, 1/40) .. {right} (.95,0);
hand2 := (hand2 .. reverse hand2 reflectedabout(left,right) .. cycle) scaled 1/2 clock_diameter;

% hour of the day to degrees
vardef htod(expr hrs)  = save h; h := hrs mod 12; h := (15-h) mod 12; h * 30 enddef;
vardef mtod(expr mins) = 6*((75-mins) mod 60) enddef;

vardef clock(expr hh, mm) = image(
  interim linecap := butt;

  fill fullcircle scaled clock_diameter withcolor (240/255, 240/255, 230/255);
  draw fullcircle scaled .9876 clock_diameter withcolor .8 white;
  draw fullcircle scaled clock_diameter withpen pencircle scaled 1;
  for t=0 step  6 until 359: draw (right scaled .475 clock_diameter -- right scaled .49 clock_diameter) rotated t; endfor
  for t=0 step 30 until 359: draw (right scaled .46  clock_diameter -- right scaled .49 clock_diameter) rotated t withpen pencircle scaled 1; endfor
  for h=1 upto 12:
    label(
      if known roman_numerals_please: 
         roman h infont "bchr8r" rotated ((12-h)*30)
      else: 
         decimal h infont "bchr8r" 
      fi,
    right scaled .41 clock_diameter rotated (((15-h) mod 12)*30)); 
  endfor
  filldraw hand1 rotated htod(hh+mm/60) withpen pencircle scaled 1;
  filldraw hand2 rotated mtod(mm)       withpen pencircle scaled 1;

  fill fullcircle scaled 1/12 clock_diameter;
  fill fullcircle scaled 1/20 clock_diameter withcolor .27 white;
  fill fullcircle scaled 1/40 clock_diameter withcolor .47 white;

) enddef;

beginfig(1)
draw clock(hour,minute)
endfig;
beginfig(2);
  roman_numerals_please := 1;
  for i=0 upto 2:
    for j=0 upto 3:
       draw clock(floor(uniformdeviate 12), 5 * floor(uniformdeviate 12)) 
            shifted (1.414i*clock_diameter, 1.414j*clock_diameter);
    endfor 
  endfor
endfig;
end
```

Comment: Is is written in plain .tex? How do I run this?

Comment: @Joseph This is METAPOST text. I can suggest you to use [BSD Owl Scripts](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl) to [easily integrate METAPOST pictures to your TeX documents](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/blob/master/doc/LaTeXDocument.md#produce-documents-including-metapost-figures).  There is [packages for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~michipili/+archive/ubuntu/bsdowl) and I hope to complete other Debian, FreeBSD and MacPorts packages until the end of the week.

Comment: @Joseph There are also the `gmp` and `luamplib` packages (the latter only for LuaLaTeX) to integrate MetaPost code in LaTeX documents. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205639/how-to-import-metapost-to-tex-properly-and-how-to-do-it-without-importing/228009#228009